# getting a user's business unit on the basis of email address MS Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I have been able to get the currently logged-in user's business unit value on the basis of the system user id. I want to get the same business unit value but, on the basis of the "internalemailaddress" or simply the user's email address.

Till now, I have been able to get the current user's email address. But, don't know how to get the business unit value on the basis of it.

Is it possible to retrieve a user's business unit on the basis of the email address of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to fecth systemuser based on your internal email or user's email and then you will have to fetch businses unit based of systemuser found.

```
   <fetch top="50">
  <entity name="systemuser">
    <attribute name="internalemailaddress" />
    <attribute name="systemuserid" />
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="internalemailaddress" operator="eq" value="abc@xyz.de" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="businessunit" from="businessunitid" to="businessunitid" link-type="inner">
      <attribute name="name" />
      <attribute name="businessunitid" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Query expression

```
// Define Condition Values
var query_internalemailaddress = "abc@xyz.de";

// Instantiate QueryExpression query
var query = new QueryExpression("systemuser");
query.TopCount = 50;

// Add columns to query.ColumnSet
query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("internalemailaddress", "systemuserid", "fullname");

// Define filter query.Criteria
query.Criteria.AddCondition("internalemailaddress", ConditionOperator.Equal, query_internalemailaddress);

// Add link-entity query_businessunit
var query_businessunit = query.AddLink("businessunit", "businessunitid", "businessunitid");

// Add columns to query_businessunit.Columns
query_businessunit.Columns.AddColumns("name", "businessunitid");
```

OData Query

```
https://CRMURL.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/systemusers?$select=internalemailaddress,systemuserid,fullname&$expand=businessunitid($select=name,businessunitid)&$filter=(internalemailaddress eq 'abc%40xyz.de') and (businessunitid/businessunitid ne null)&$top=50
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT TOP 50 internalemailaddress, systemuserid, fullname, businessunit.name, businessunit.businessunitid
FROM systemuser
JOIN businessunit businessunit ON businessunit.businessunitid = systemuser.businessunitid
WHERE internalemailaddress = 'abc@xyz.de'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AnkUser. It gave me the desired business unit id. I have one question. How can I make the email id dynamic?